# Facebook Contest and User Registration Date

Tags: user-registration, userid

i'm developing a Facebook Contest (in Italy) and here i must verify that a user is registred to FB before the contest starts...

But, how can i verify this...?

In the FB API i don't find nothing that helps me (to this goal).

A related question can be :

are FB user ids progressive ? so if i have a userId 10 was born before userId 100 ?
(i ask because after my tries it seems doesn't work)...

so i ask if there's a way to verify this..

THANKS..!!!